# Xpath expression in mule

Tags: xpath, mule

I have a requirement to call a rest api which gives the below xml response. I want to extract the field 'EntryID' using xpath only. Can some one please help me with the xpath expression and what transformer I need to use after http outbound. I am using Mule 3.5.0 version.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <entry>
       <author>
            <name>teden</name>
        </author>
        <contributor>
            <name>angelaw</name>
        </contributor>
        <content type="xhtml">
            <Entry>
                <EntryID>53339</EntryID>                
            </Entry>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Mule flow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <mulexml:namespace-manager
        includeConfigNamespaces="true">
        <mulexml:namespace prefix="v1"
            uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
    </mulexml:namespace-manager>
    <mulexml:xml-to-dom-transformer name="Parse_XML"
        doc:name="Parse XML Message" />
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8081" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <transformer ref="Parse_XML" doc:name="Transformer Reference" />
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[flowVars.test= xpath('/v1:feed/entry/content/Entry/EntryID/text()').text;]]></expression-component>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **Mule 3.5 runtime** you can use following way to get results

Place Mule Namespace Manager Globally:

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
      <mulexml:namespace prefix="v1" uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
 </mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Make sure you add namespace for namespace Manager :

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
```

ref: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/xml-namespaces

**update**:

You can extract data using **XPATH** expressions in MEL:

```
 <logger message="#[xpath('/v1:feed/v1:entry/v1:content/v1:Entry/v1:EntryID/text()').text]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```